# How to pass a dynamically-created paramater to a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, dynamically-generated

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const aTag = $(`<div>`)
  let elem = array[i].numberID    //<--want to pass 'elem' into seeTrailer() on click
    aTag.attr('onClick', seeTrailer(elem))  //<--but this doesn't work
    trailerHref.attr('id', elem)
    ...
  }

  seeTrailer (id) => {
    const apikey=123456789;
    const queryURL = `https://url/${id}?api_key=${apikey};
    ...
  }
```

Comment: You could try this a different way, so you could set elem (which I think is an int) into a data element in your aTag and then when clicked just get it back out.

Comment: Side note; you're using jQuery.  Don't set inline attributes .... Use the proper `on()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(<ELEM>).click()` method of jQuery, and also set the ID attribute while creating the element as followings:

```
  let elem = array[i].numberID 
  const aTag = $(`<div/>`,{
     id: elem
  })


  aTag.click(function(){
     seeTrailer(elem)
  })
```